# UITableView bouncing back to the top of a section when calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

When a user taps a button in one of my rows I am updating the underlying model for that row and then calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths for the given row (i.e. single row reload).

```
- (IBAction)handleCompleteTouchEvent:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForView:sender];
    id item = [self dataForIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(completed)]) {
        // toogle completed value
        BOOL completed = ![[item valueForKey:@"completed"] boolValue];
        [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:completed] forKey:@"completed"];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the table view bounces back to the top of the section after making this call. How can I prevent this from occurring and keep the scroll position where it is?

Comment: Code looks OK. Can you share more code that can be relevant to the problem? Is there any place in the code if your view controller where you call `[self.tableView reloadData];`?

Comment: I added more code to show the entire method. Once reloadRowsAtIndexPaths is called the table automatically scrolls to the top of the section but only when the section header is off the screen. There is nothing special about the cell creation or the section header (just a string).

Comment: @Keenle I am not performing any reloadData or anything like that. Also, there isn't anything in the documentation about bouncing to the top of a section on a reloadRows. I have never noticed this functionality before but then again I don't typically have data changing actions within the cell itself so this is a new type of interaction for me.

Comment: Try to check the value of `indexPath` received from `indexPathForView`. It can be `nil`. If so it must be causing scroll to the top.

Comment: @Keenle the indexPath is correct. It was the first thing I checked. Besides, it does not bounce to the top of the table (0,0). It bounces to the top of the section (1,0).

Comment: This surely is a bug and still not fixed !

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ah Ha! I found the problem and am going to answer my own question for the poor soul who runs into this issue in the future.

All of my cells have variable height so I was using the new iOS7 method in UITableViewDelegate thinking it might speed up render time (not that I really needed it):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Anyway, implementing this method has the evil side effect of causing the table to bounce to the top of the section when calling:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

To solve the bounce problem I just removed the override of that estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method and now everything works as it should. Happy at last.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using "self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight" caused that bouncing of the table view in my case.

Comment: Hello @xsee, if I am using autoLayout, if I dont use extimatedRowHeight, then on adding there will be a problem and the rows will get shrink

Comment: You saved a tons of my time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same issue, except I actually want to use estimatedRowHeight. I found that by setting the estimatedRowHeight to a number larger than the actual height of the cell seems to improve the behavior slightly (the table view only scrolls a little bit).

Comment: Is there no real solution to this issue though? It seems like a bug on Apple's part?

Comment: So strange! Thank you :)

Comment: estimatedRowHeight is required when using UITableViewAutomaticDimension in iOS8.

Comment: I set `estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight` in `viewDidLoad` and this seems to help a bit. I'm also using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: Strange issue, was looking for solution. In my case, i used self sizing cells with estimatedRowHeight. I just change value for estimatedRowHeight greater than cell's height.Now result is good.

Comment: `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0f;` also works

Comment: Removing those 2 bloody lines saved me. Thanks! Can't thank you enough!!!

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick for me.

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [...], with: .none)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

This can work anywhere you want to remove animation.
During reload of table , table section or any row

```
 UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
                cell.configureSelection(isSelected: true)
                tableView.reloadSections([1], with: .none)
                tableView.allowsSelection =  false

            })
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do what you are trying to do by changing the cell contents directly. For example, if you are using the base `UITableViewCell` class and the data in your model is a `NSString` which you show in the table view cell, you can do the following (after you change your data model) instead of calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *label = [cell textLabel];
label.text = @"New Value";
```

If you are using a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, it's roughly the same except for accessing the views of the cell will need to be done through the contentView property.

Comment: This solution works but I don't like it. Imagine if I want to flip out the entire cell prototype based on a change to the data model. I wouldn't be able to do this without reloading the row but then I am back to square one with the "bounce to top of section" issue. If I can't get a better answer (or workaround) to the problem with the reload then I will accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to put the cell in it's own section and call reload section:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

this appears to fix the issue partially. Not the cleanest way but it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In my similar case, I had to tweak the implementation of method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
}
```

where my heights were being reset. So, instead of resetting height for every cell I updated only the effected cells for **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** call.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the minimum height of your cell, you must specify that while setting `estimatedRowHeight`. I was setting it to 1 as I have read before somewhere that any value above 0 would suffice the purpose, but it was the culprit.

When I set it to 44, which was the minimum height my cell could have, all went fine.

Dynamic heights were also working fine, no issues with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

To build off xsee's answer - 
I had set the `Estimate` in interface builder to "automatic". I changed this to another number and it started working. I kept `Row Height` to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I ended up just calling tableView.reloadData() instead after updating my data / cell and it didn't bounce back to the top / data was updated in place - FYI

Answer (score 0):

This solved this issue for me with **Swift 5 / iOS 14**:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation({
   self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [self.idxTouched], with: .none)
})
```