# NSFetchedResultsController can't scroll while table updating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with `NSFetchedResultsController` that listen for item updates.

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

 func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                }
            case .Delete:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                }
            case .Update:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                }
            default:
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        self.items = controller.fetchedObjects as! [Item]
    }

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

When user add item i update it in database every 1-2 seconds and i can't scroll down, because controller refresh item and scroll me to top.

Comment: Do you also have `controllerWillChangeContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent` implemented?

Comment: yes, i updated answer

Comment: so you can't scroll down because your tableView is reloading and taking you back to the top?

Comment: i printed results: Update ,method was call every time... So only one row should be update

Comment: just curious.. why no rowAnimation if you are inserting and deleting rows? Get rid of that `self.tableView.reloadData()` and see if that fixes your problem... you don't need to reload the entire tableView data, because you are already updating it with your `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, and `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` methods... thats redundant and might be the cause of your problems

Comment: i tried, doesn't help... I tried add animations, not helped too

Comment: How is your NSFetchedResultsController being updated every 1-2 seconds?  You should expect performance issues if you reload the tableView every second

Comment: I have NSOperationQueue with max 5 threads. And have a list with 50 items, and in every iteration i put operation to queue  and inside background thread it update Item.

Comment: ```for item in items {
            GVariables.globalBackgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){
             // update my Item object
}}```

Comment: and task can take 2 seconds or 15 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem. It is because i use:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Thanks for this answer: [UITableView bouncing back to the top of a section when calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767665/uitableview-bouncing-back-to-the-top-of-a-section-when-calling-reloadrowsatindex)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the default case? It's reloading your table view every time an item moves.

Try to implement the .Move case like is described on this post: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: maybe need to check if cell is visible ?