# Reloading table view cell from block causing scroll jump in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm experiencing an issue in a `UITableView` in iOS 11. If I reload a table view cell with the `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` row animation in a block it causes the table view to scroll jump when the animation occurs. It happens for me in an alert action for an alert controller. How do I prevent that from happening? Here is an example.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    // save
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // this causes a scroll jump when called in this block
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   
    }]];

    // cancel
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

EDIT: This is different than the duplicate in question. My table view is not  scrolling to the top of a section. It's just scroll jumping maybe 10 pixels if you are scrolled down from the top when the table view cell is reloaded with the fade animation.

Comment: use `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`

Comment: I want it to be animated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView bouncing back to the top of a section when calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767665/uitableview-bouncing-back-to-the-top-of-a-section-when-calling-reloadrowsatindex)

Comment: I'm not using `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Hmmm... quick test with `Basic` prototype cells, and I'm not seeing any jumping? Full VC is here: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/beec6d563c607e31ca0d0caf5d3edc65

Comment: It only happens when you are scrolled down in the view. If you are completely scrolled up to the top you won't see the scroll jump.

Comment: I believe this may be a bug regarding how iOS 11 (I'm not sure when this feature was introduced) will dynamically size table view cells without having to override any delegate methods if your text and detail labels have multiple lines.

Comment: Edited my test... Custom cell with multiline Top and Bottom labels, and constraints set for "auto-sizing"... scroll down to various rows... still don't see a "jump" when changing the data (including adding lines of text) and calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`... updated gist: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/46d529793b066de803bd9a59a06a2de2

Comment: Do you have a small, reproducible example?