# UITableView scroll to top when call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xib

I used UITableViewCell using xib. I want to change some subview's height constraint of cell content view. Code for that is

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        simpleLearningCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"simpleCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell =  [[simpleLearningCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"simpleCell"];
        }

        cell.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Vipin Sharma @ WDP Technologies Pvt Ltd"];
        cell.lblTxtDetail.text = @"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200.";


        [cell.btnShare setButtonWithTitle:@"share with collegue" iconName:@"sharearrow" andWidthConstraints:cell.btnshareWidthConstraint];

        [cell.btnComment addTarget:self action:@selector(doComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row+1;

        if (indexPath.row == selectIndex) {

            if (cell.txtCommentViewHeight.constant == 0) {

                cell.txtCommentViewHeight.constant = 43;

            }else{

                cell.txtCommentViewHeight.constant = 0;
            }
        }else{
            cell.txtCommentViewHeight.constant = 0;
        }

        return cell;
}
```

method call at time of cell button click

```
#pragma mark: do comment
-(void)doComment:(UIButton*)sender{
    selectIndex = (int)sender.tag-1;
    NSIndexPath*indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag-1 inSection:0];
    [self.tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

when I reload `UITableView` it auto scroll to top. also constant of `cell.txtCommentViewHeight` changed after 2 tap.

Comment: Did you try to call `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` after change constants?

Comment: @trungduc same issue I tried

Comment: have a look at here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770000/8918347

Comment: @GovindKumawat already checked same issue. I resolved it by setting content offset but am not able to detect why table scroll to top till now.